# Comparing letters in list with string in a list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list lets say:

DIRECTION_LETTERS=['u', 'd' ,'r' , 'l', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

Now the other parameter of mine is like arguement, I write in

udl and it returns ['udl']

so lets say another list arg_list = ['udl']

I want to check if u and d and l is in this list or i want to check if none of the letters in my direction letters list in the arg list
to make it print error msg I have tried this:

```
    for letter in DIRECTION_LETTERS:
    for char in arg_list[4]:
        if letter in arg_list[4][0]:
            continue
        else:
            print (ERROR_MESSAGE_DIRECTIONS)
            return False


return True
```

Comment: Can you tidy up your question and include input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
if letter in arg_list[4][0]:
```

needs to be

```
if char in DIRECTION_LETTERS:
```

and you need to delete the line `for letter in DIRECTION_LETTERS:`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a handy function in Python called `all()` which returns true if all arguments are true. Feel free to find a nice way of using it, but in general:

```
>>> DIRECTION_LETTERS=['u', 'd' ,'r' , 'l', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> 
>>> s="udl"
>>> print(all(c in DIRECTION_LETTERS for c in s))
True
>>> s="udlxa"
>>> print(all(c in DIRECTION_LETTERS for c in s))
False
```

Comment: Thanks you learned me  something new aswell but in my assigment sadly i cannot use what they haven't learned me in class